# Changing links, from id to names

Tags: php, mysql, mod-rewrite, seo, e-commerce

I have build a e-commerce site (in php, i'm not specialist in programming, just what i learned from tutorials) and now I want to change how the links look like.

In PHP the are like this: `www.example.ro/product.php?id=100`

I made rewrite rules and php redirections and now they are like:

```
www.example.ro/man-shoes/man-shoes-100
```

But what I want to do is to replace that id "100" with a particular name for each product,
something like:

```
www.example.ro/man-shoes/man-shoes-lois
```

I think this kind of links are more seo friendly.
Can someone help me with how i should integrate this? I have no idea from where to start.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

The name that your find is SLUG, but the implementation varying of the ecommerce framework you have used.
Recommend you to reading this [How do I use custom URLS page slugs](http://www.corecommerce.com/kb/16562/how_do_i_use_custom_urls_page_slugs)